# Exponential trigonometric integral

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, orientation, trigonometric-functions

I want to compute the normalization constant of some probability density on SO(3). After some simplification, I arrive at the following double integral:

$$ \tag{1}\label{eq:1}
\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^{\pi} \sin y \,\exp ( \kappa \max ( \sin y \,\lvert \cos x \rvert, \sin y \,\lvert \sin x \rvert, \lvert \cos y \rvert )) \, \text{d}y \,\text{d}x.
$$

We can divide the region $I = (0, 2 \pi ) \times (0, \pi )$ into ten blocks $I_1 , \dots , I_{10}$ given by the following diagram:
[image]

On each of those regions, we can remove the absolute values and reduce the maximum of three items to a maximum of two items. For example for $I_1$ we have

$$ \tag{2}\label{eq:2}
\int_0^{\pi /4} \int_0^{\pi /2} \sin y \,\exp(\kappa \max(\sin y \cos x, \cos y))\, \text{d}y\, \text{d}x. 
$$

Furthermore, we can divide $I_1$ into two regions by a curve

$$ \tag{3}\label{eq:3}
y = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan x , \ x \in (0 , \pi /4 ). 
$$

On the "lower" region, the maximum is equal to $\cos y$. Hence, the integral over the "lower" region is equal to

$$ \tag{4}\label{eq:4}
\int_0^{\pi /4} \int_0^{ \pi /2 - \arctan x } \sin y \,\exp( \kappa \cos y)\, \text{d}y \,\text{d}x = \int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{e^\kappa}{\kappa} - \frac{1}{\kappa} e^{ \frac{\kappa x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} } \,\text{d}x. 
$$

The integral over the "upper" region is equal to

$$ \tag{5}\label{eq:5}
\int_0^{\pi /4} \int_{\pi /2 - \arctan x}^{\pi/2} \sin y \, \exp( \kappa \sin y \cos x) \,\text{d}y\, \text{d}x. 
$$

However, I do not know how to finish those integrals. I would appreciate any hints.

**Update**

As was pointed out in the comment, the division curved of the "upper" and "lower" region is actually

$$ \tag{3a}\label{eq:3a}
y = \arctan( \sec x) , \ x \in (0, \pi /4 ) .
$$

Then the integral over the "lower" region is equal to

$$ \tag{4a}\label{eq:4a}
\int_0^{\pi /4} \int_0^{\arctan(\sec x)} \sin y \,\exp ( \kappa \cos y) \, \text{d}y \, \text{d}x = \int_0^{\pi /4} \frac{ \pi }{4 \kappa} \bigg( e^{\kappa} - e^{ \frac{\kappa}{\sqrt{1+ \sec^2 x}} } \bigg)\, \text{d}x .
$$

Integral over the "upper" region is equal to

$$ \tag{5a}\label{eq:5a}
\int_0^{\pi /4} \int_0^{\arctan( \sec x)} \sin y \, \exp ( \kappa \sin y \cos x) \, \text{d}y \, \text{d}x.
$$

However, I cannot use substitution as in the previous case.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in (3), as the solution of $\sin y\cos x=\cos y$ is $y=\arctan(\sec x)$ for $x\in(0,\pi/4)$.
Then, the last integral (5) is twice your second last integral (4). So the problem reduces to the integral
$$
\int_0^{\pi/4} \exp[\kappa \, (1+\sec^2 x)^{-1/2}] \, \mathrm{d}x
=
\int_{1/\sqrt 3}^{1/\sqrt 2} \frac{e^{\kappa \,\xi}}
{\sqrt{1-4\xi^2+5\xi^4-2\xi^6}} \, \mathrm{d}\xi \, .
$$
I don't think the last integral is solvable.

Comment: The integral in my last comment can be further simplified, leading to the expression for the OP's integral (1) $$ \mathcal I=\frac{48}{\kappa}\left( \frac {\pi\,e^\kappa} 4 - \sqrt 2 \int_0^{\arccos\sqrt{2/3}}\frac{e^{\frac{\kappa}{\sqrt 2} \cos\varphi}}{2-\cos^2\varphi}\right). $$

Comment: @FredHucht Differentiating the integral $I(\kappa)$ twice leads to $$I''(\kappa\sqrt2)-I(\kappa\sqrt2)=-\frac12\int_0^{\arccos\sqrt{2/3}}e^{\kappa\cos\varphi}\,d\varphi$$ so closed form not expected.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my comments as an answer: Based on my short study as well as also on the comment by @TheSimpliFire, I am quite sure that the best one can get is the integral representation below, or a modification of it.

By symmetry, the region $I$ of the original integral \eqref{eq:1} can be decomposed into 16 equal regions $I_1$, such that (I'll use the more familiar spherical angles $y\mapsto\theta$ and $x\mapsto\varphi$ and multiply by an additional factor $\kappa/48$)
\begin{align}
\mathcal I(\kappa) 
&= \tag{A1a}\label{eq:A1a}
\frac{\kappa}{48}\int_0^{2 \pi} \text{d}\varphi \int_0^{\pi} \text{d}\theta
\,\sin \theta \,e^{ \kappa \max ( \sin \theta \,\lvert \cos \varphi \rvert, \sin \theta \,\lvert \sin \varphi \rvert, \lvert \cos \theta \rvert )} \\
&= \tag{A1b}\label{eq:A1b}
\frac{\kappa}{3}\int_0^{\pi/4} \text{d}\varphi \int_0^{\pi/2} \text{d}\theta
\,\sin\theta \,e^{\kappa \max(\sin\theta \cos\varphi, \cos\theta )}\,.
\end{align}

The solution of $\sin\theta\cos\varphi=\cos\theta$ is $\theta=\arctan\sec \varphi$ for $\varphi\in(0,\pi/4)$.
Then, the integral \eqref{eq:5a} is twice the integral \eqref{eq:4a}. So the problem reduces to
\begin{align}
\mathcal I(\kappa)
\tag{A2a}\label{eq:A2a}
&= \kappa\int_0^{\pi/4} \text{d}\varphi \int_0^{\arctan\sec\varphi} \text{d}\theta\,\sin\theta \,e^{\kappa \cos\theta}\\
\tag{A2b}\label{eq:A2b}
&= \int_0^{\pi/4} \text{d}\varphi \left( e^\kappa-e^{\frac{\kappa}{\sqrt{1+\sec^2\varphi}}}\right) \\
\tag{A2c}\label{eq:A2c}
&=\frac {\pi\,e^\kappa} 4 -  
\int_0^{\pi/4} \text{d}\varphi \, e^{\frac{\kappa}{\sqrt{1+\sec^2\varphi}}} \\
\tag{A2d}\label{eq:A2d}
&=\frac {\pi\,e^\kappa} 4 - \sqrt 2 \int_0^{\arccos\sqrt{2/3}} \text{d}\psi\frac{e^{\frac{\kappa}{\sqrt 2} \cos\psi}}{2-\cos^2\psi}\,,
\end{align}
where the last line follows from the substitution $\cos\psi=\sqrt{2/(1+\sec^2\varphi)}$.
As noted by @TheSimpliFire, $\mathcal I$ fulfills
$$
\tag{A3}\label{eq:A3}
\mathcal I''(\kappa)-\mathcal I(\kappa)= -\frac 1 {\sqrt{2}}
\int_0^{\arccos\sqrt{2/3}} \text{d}\psi \,e^{\frac{\kappa}{\sqrt 2} \cos\psi}\,,
$$
which makes a "closed form" solution quite unlikely.